# Do not navigate to the next screen in VB

Tags: vb6, user-controls

These are myfirst steps towards VB/UI programming. In a vbp project I have user control screen as below,

[image]

I wanted following validations,

1. If SalesYes is opted and No SalesId entered it has to display SalesId required.
2. If none of the option selected then it has to display either one of the option required.
3. In both cases it should not allow to navigate to next screen

Though I am able to manage the points 1 and 2, it is going to the next screen because I have no control over Next/Finish button which out of scope of the project.

Could you please help in not allowing the control to go to the next screen until the condition 1 and 2 are true?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you have no control over the Next/Finish button, I don't think you will be able to stop the user from clicking it. You could make the user control's background red to indicate the selected options are invalid but that would not stop the user from moving forward.

Comment: I was typing almost an identical response as you received from Etienne so I won't repeat it.  But in addition I would say this: from a user perspective I would expect the "Next/Finish" to be grayed-out until points 1 and 2 are valid.  So any hack you might come up with to prevent advancing to the next screen would not be pleasant for the user.

Comment: If we are unable to stop being advancing to next screen, can we show the same screen based on the condition, something like salesFrom.show(). If so how that can achieved?

Comment: Would it also be out of scope to question the design requirements?  You have radio buttons for "yes/no", but "yes" always requires SalesId, and No requires it to be blank.  Would a caption saying "Sales Id (Leave blank for none):" be just as good for input in a case like this?

Comment: If possible, don't allow the case where no options are selected. Default it to one of them, then there is no way for the user to deselect an option.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that there is no mechanism to influence the Next/Finish buttons? That seems like a strange design. Could there be an event that you have to handle, or some boolean `m_bCanAdvance` variable, or anything like that?

Comment: @StayOnTarget, Yes no mechanism to access directly, not sure how that has been done. If there is any possibility to do with in the existing layout then that amounts simple and fast approach.